# Macbook Pro Retina with ubuntu 13.10 having trouble waking up from suspend

Tags: 13.10, suspend, macbook-pro

Computer: Macbook pro retina 2012
Ubuntu 13.10

The screen becomes black with lit keyboards when I try waking up my computer after closing the lid or suspending from terminal.

Attempt at solution:
I tried changing grub command to "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force", it gives me the log in screen, but after typing in my credentials the screen reverts to black.

Does this have to do with my default graphics card being nouveau? (Additional driver doesn't show the nvidia graphics card).

I am extremely new to ubuntu, so any suggestion would be appreciated =]

EDIT:
error log - [http://imgur.com/sDlCEGf](https://imgur.com/sDlCEGf) (i dont have enough reputations to post screenshot..)

cont - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYnVR.jpg

Comment: After reboot, do you get any reports sounding like 'Ubuntu 13.10 has expected internal system error"? It should contain useful data to us. Thanks! 

BTW it might be unsupported motherboard, had the same problem

Comment: Yes on reboot it does give me that error message, and the motherboard is Intel Core i7. How do i post the error message?

Comment: enlarge the box to maximum and send screenshot

Comment: i posted the screenshot

Comment: I see, can you slide down so I can see the last thing at top? And By the way, what graphic card do you have?

Comment: I have nvidia gt 650m, and i will take the screenshot as soon as i get home. On ubuntu under graphics card it says gallium nouveau.

Comment: http://imgur.com/11bNTL6 here is the bottom part

Comment: Where should i start looking?

Comment: hmm looks kinda weird, 'cause nothing seems wrong

Comment: Seems like the nouveau driver problem, I've had the same. It's weird that you don't have the drivers in the list. You can try doing it manually though.

Comment: happy new year! how do i do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing kernel 3.13 RC 6 have fixed the problem with the black screen from suspend.

Follow the instructions here:
http://linuxg.net/kernel-3-13-rc-6-has-been-released-how-to-install-kernel-3-13-rc-6-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-pear-os-and-elementary-os/